# Is it efficient to visualize chords on sheet music as notes on a piano to know the qualities of it?

Tags: chords, sheet-music

For example, say you see sheet music (you are not in front of a piano) and you see the notes D F A . Is it efficient enough to visualize these notes as on a piano to determine that they are a minor chord or is there another more efficient way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the point of the question. Are you worried that you're learning some bad habits by visualizing the notes on your instrument?

Comment: @user1079505 yes, whenever I see a chord on sheet music I see the notes as notes on a piano to find out the qualities of the chord, and if there is a better way to find the qualities of the chord in sheet music, I want to break out of my habit and use the more efficient method instead

Comment: Seems to me “effective” might be more important than “efficient.” And if it works for you…

Comment: That's essentially how I started out, and I wouldn't say that's fundamentally changed, I'm just less reliant on it. Of course any experienced musician will "just know" that the notes D F A form a D minor chord, but there's no rule that you can't "just know" and visualize at the same time.

Comment: …Well, that and recognition of chord shapes helping to quickly identify the root, more than anything to do with each individual note.

Comment: No, it is certainly not efficient. You should be able to read a sequence of chord names and know what it would sound like without (a) constructing them into their constituent notes, (b) visualising them on a piano or any other instrument, and then (c) intuiting what *that* would sound like. It might be *effective* for you, for the time being, but it is not *efficient*, and you need to move beyond it. Quickly. When reading music and performing it in real time you don't have the time for all this.

Comment: @user207421 Efficiency is not that simple, and it certainly is not the result of absolute paths when dealing with mental capabilities, as each one of us have different ways of interpreting and relating to abstract structures. Music learning and understanding is extremely complex, and being efficient is about being able to put the less efforts in obtaining the result, which depends on a plethora of aspects when dealing with such complex forms, including experience, knowledge and, not less important, purpose. While some approaches *may* be more efficient than others, no one can be to everybody.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, mostly. It’s not the most efficient way but it’s a good way to learn the most efficient way which is to just know DFA is minor as soon as you see it on the page. A good way to memorize and know chord qualities it to spend a lot of time evaluating chord qualities on the page using some slower method, and visualizing the piano is probably the best slower method.

One other thing you might do is learn to rattle off all the thirds quickly so you always know what’s a third above or below any note. As in, ACEGBDFA. Or if you prefer, GBDFACEG. Whatever makes sense to you. This can also help with reading sheet music because lines are thirds apart and spaces are thirds apart.

Answer (score 2):

Since the piano keyboard is 'graphic' - unlike most other instruments, it's the one that most students are expected to be familiar with, regardless of their primary instrument. Thus, using it as a template is a very good idea. The sharps/flats stand out, and the white keys form a pattern that's easily discernible and memorable - as you're finding.

I think most of us *eventually* leave that concept behind, as we've learned which notes constitute which flavours of chords, and will play the appropriate notes accordingly. Or see the notes, and just 'know' what sort of chord they constitute.

You ask specifically about *qualities* of a chord. Suffice to know that it's the interval between root and ^3 that dictate this - m3 =minor, M3 =major, as a basis.

As Todd says, the note sequences using notes on only lines, or only spaces, will be of assistance, but - need to bear in mind any accidentals, or key signatures that are applied. And using that method may not be as effective as visualising the ubiquitous piano keyboard. So, eventually (months, years) you'll just 'know' the different 'formulae' for all the chords!

Comment: "Most of us"? How I wish. As an amateur singer, I just wish that when the MD says "we'll sing the E-flat-major section" I could just see it on the page the way he does, but I'm a long way from achieving that. For me, it has to go via the mental image of the piano keyboard.

Comment: @MichaelKay - like I say, months , years, which I suspect the MD has.

Comment: I agree, adding that connections among aural/visual/tactile realms often are helpful even for advanced musicians. I never visualize a piano keyboard to know a chord quality (I don't ever remember doing that, but maybe I did when I was rather young). But even as someone with advanced theory knowledge and who has taught music theory, I will still find myself virtually "playing" a piece I don't know while moving my fingers as if I were playing an invisible piano to help "hear" it internally. (I don't generally do it in front of other people, but the aural/kinesthetic connection is helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to 'count up' to see how many semitones are between each note, visualizing a keyboard is a good way.  A guitarist might 'count frets' in much the same way.   Eventually you'll just *know* that D, F, A is a D minor triad, in the same way as you don't have to spell out C,A,T, you just know it spells 'cat'.

(Any particular reason you NEED to analyze in this way?)